# Fractional space

Tags: fractional-sobolev-spaces

I have the following fractional partial differetial equation

$$
\dfrac{\partial x(z,t)}{\partial t}=\dfrac{\partial ^\alpha x(z,t)}{\partial z^\alpha}
$$
with $1\leq \alpha \leq 2$ and $0<z<1$. The Caputo definition is considered for the fractional derivative.

How to chose the space for $x(z,t)$?

Answer (score 0):

Subtleties concerning the boundary conditions arise. Try to have a look at [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.07991)